# How does one populate a Lightning component combobox with a list of records (id/name)?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, list, javascript-controller, helper, lightning-combobox

I have a Lightning component in which I want to display a list of records related to an Account. I currently have this (but it doesn't work):

My Component display:

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.issues))}">
    <div class="slds-form-element__row">
        <div class="slds-form-element slds-size_1-of-2">
            <lightning:combobox name="issues" label="Issue" placeholder="Select an Issue" options="{!v.issues}" onchange="{!c.selectIssue}"/>                    
        </div>
    </div>
</aura:if>
```

The Helper code:

```
var issueOpt = response.getReturnValue().issues;
var issues = [];
if(issueOpt.length > 0){
    for (var i = 0; i < issueOpt.length; i++){
        //var issueOption = issueOpt[i].toString();
        var item = {
            "label": issueOpt[i].Id.toString(),
            "value": issueOpt[i].Name.toString(),
        };
        issues.push(item);                            
    }
}
component.set("v.issues", issues);
```

The Controller simply runs a query that populates a list of 'issue' object records (Id, Name). It falls over in the Helper code - what am I doing wrong?

**Update**:
In editing my code as @sfdcfox has suggested in my Helper class, I have also changed the attribute in my component from a list to a map:

```
<aura:attribute name="issues" type="Map" default="{}"/>
```

This is in my controller:

```
@AuraEnabled
public List<Issue__c> issues {get;set;} // List of issues for Account   

....., and the query:

List<AggregateResult> incomes = [Select Issue__c, Issue__r.Name 
                           From Income__c Where Account__c =: account.Id
                           group by Issue__c, Issue__r.Name];
Issue__c issue = new Issue__c();
issues = new list<Issue__c>();
for(AggregateResult aggr:incomes){ 
    issue.Id = (Id)aggr.get('Issue__c');
    issue.Name = (String)aggr.get('Name');
    issues.add(issue);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We'd have to see the return value from your Apex, but the proper code to populate this usually goes something like this:

```
var retVal = response.getReturnValue().issues;
var opts = retVal.map(opt => ({ value: opt.Id, label: opt.Name }));
component.set("v.issues", opts);
```

You would not ordinarily call `toString()` on the values returned from Apex, as they are already string values.

Comment: and calling `toString()` on `null` or `undefined` vars throws `Uncaught TypeError` so the issue might be there.

Comment: @OlehBerehovskyi indeed, I just didn't want to make too many assumptions. Although, assuming it's a list of record values, Name would never be null, nor would Id (both are "required" for most types of records in Salesforce).

Comment: @sfdcfox I've put your code in and tried it, but am getting this error: Uncaught Error in $A.getCallback() [Cannot read property 'map' of undefined] - this is when the list is empty. I need to catch that - how would I do that?

Comment: @Irene Empty, or null? Ideally, you should not be returning a null value back from Apex. This makes it more complicated twice: once in Apex to return a null value, then again in Lightning to check if it is null. If there are no values, return an empty list.

Comment: @sfdcfox you are so right - I'd forgotten to initialise the list in the controller! Works perfectly now :)